# Goalseek with VBA using a Value in a named cell as goal value

Tags: vba

Hi I'm trying to build a goalseek in VBA using a value from a named cell as the target value. I used the following source code and it does not work.
Can you please help me?

Thanks!

```
Worksheets("Assumptions & Results").Range("EIRRHybrid").GoalSeek Goal:=Worksheets("Assumptions & Results").Range("TargetEIRR").Value, ChangingCell:=Worksheets("Assumptions & Results").Range("Revenues_for_PV")
```

Comment: I should probably add that my target value in Cell "TargetEIRR" is 15%.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure that `EIRRHybrid` has formula, that refers directly or indirectly to the `ChangingCell` (named range `Revenues_for_PV`)

Second, range `Revenues_for_PV` should be a *single cell*. If your range `Revenues_for_PV` contains more than one cell, you can use [**Solver**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196600.aspx) instead, or use `.Range("Revenues_for_PV").Cells(1, 1)` to change only first cell.

I also recommend you to use `With` statement. It makes your code more clear and faster:

```
With Worksheets("Assumptions & Results")
    .Range("EIRRHybrid").GoalSeek _
        Goal:=.Range("TargetEIRR").Value, _
        ChangingCell:=.Range("Revenues_for_PV").Cells(1,1)
End With
```